# Angular UI Map Not Updating for Scope Changes

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui

I am trying to update the Angular [ui-map](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-map) when the scope changes. I have added a `$watch` and I can see the scope change in console but the map is not updating with the change in latitude and longitude. This is what I have:

```
        $scope.mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 4,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var updateCenter = function() {
                    $scope.mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 11,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng($scope.fromLat, $scope.fromLng),
                    };
                    console.log($scope.mapOptions);
              }
              $scope.$watch('fromLat', updateCenter);
              $scope.$watch('fromLng', updateCenter);
```

Where the `$scope.fromLat` and `$scope.fromLng` are the scope changes that I am watching. When I log these scopes in console I can see the scopes updated. But the map is still on the initial state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this is what I did to resolve this issue. I did 2 changes:

**1) Used setCentre() in Controller:**

In the `updateCenter()` method, instead of updating the `$scope.mapOptions`, I used `setCenter()` to directly change the map center.

```
var updateCenter = function() {
    $scope.myMap.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng($scope.fromLat, $scope.fromLng));
}
```

Here, `myMap` is the scope added to `ui-map` like this:

```
div ui-map="myMap" ui-options="mapOptions" class="google-map"></div>
```

**2) ng-change in View or $watch:**

Secondly, I added a `$watch` for updating the map instantly. There are 2 ways:

- I can add `ng-change` attribute to the input scope that calls the above function when the latitude and longitudes scopes are changed. This way the map change is in effect immediately.

  `<input id="fromLat" type="text" ng-model="fromLat" ng-change="updateMap()" name="fromLat" />`
- Or add a `$watch` in controller:

  `$scope.$watch('fromLat', updateCenter);`